# Which tool is the best option for doing search in Datagrid in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created search option using combobox, for example 
        In combobox1 items are m1,m2,m3,m4,m5 based on that, if m1 item selected then
        another combobox2 displays with items a,b,c,d and if a item is selected another
        combobox3 dispalys, based on last combobox it searches on the datagrid.
        I think it is long process, use of many combobox makes it lenghty. Is any
        other way is their to implement this. plz help

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      x:Name="cmbType" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsOther}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource enumTypeOfType}}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SearchType,Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedIndex="{Binding CmdResIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      SelectionChanged="DataSource1"
                      Margin="0,0,1,0">
                    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Combobox 1 filters > Combobox 2 filters > Combobox 3 filters > Datagrid.

You basically mean this?

Comment: Yes, that is what.. but instead of combo.. can i use any other tool?

Comment: You can try showing multiple `ListView`,and they filter depending on `SelectedIValue`?

Comment: Yes correct. but listview consume more space than combobox rite.

Comment: True...but the user can see all the data without clicking the other two comboboxes.

Comment: Yes but User can see all data in datagrid itself.. what we want is, we want to search particular hiding it wenever search option not clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i get this right, you have a collection a, which goes to collection b,etc, and the second collection will change based on the selected item of the first? You have to remember, that since the data will change for each selection, hard coding the value is out of the question.

Knowing this, WPF provides you with a great mechanism for this. Using a stackpanel, with a list view will actually work.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{binding collections}" ItemTemplate="{binding TemplateForListViewItems}" ItemPanelTemplate="{binding itemPanelTemplate}"></ItemsControl>
```

Now, with the items control, one can simply set an ItemTemplate/DataTemplate, to set the styling of each control. Linking to the onclick event, or using interactions, you can simply do collections.Add to add your new list view with generated data for the selection, and done.